# Recognise input made with Sikuli/Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, applet, sikuli

I've been messing around with Sikuli and Selenium. Yesterday I tried using it to log in on a certain page. This page uses an Java applet for login in so naturally I used Sikuli for the input of text. Now, this java applet works very well when i log in manually, however, when I try to log in using my application, the page returns a cryptic message. I've been trying all kinds of stuff and the only thing I can think of is that they somehow recognise that the input of text is made by sikuli, and not a real human.

My question is, how does this work?

Comment: How about posting some code? See [ask] for details.

Answer (score 0):

Even I haven't tried using Sikuli for text input.
But I hope following code works,

```
Screen sikuliObject = new Screen();

Pattern image = new Pattern(Path of the Screen shot);

 //Click on the image
sikuliObject.click(image);
sikuliObject.type("Your String");
```

FYI: Using Sikuli is not a best practice with selenium, as we can easily do it using selenium.